# Can USA's president launch nukes whenever/wherever?

Tags: united-states, war

Many people complaining the current (or former) president of USA mention the fact that "he has the ability to launch nukes wherever and whenever he wants", "he has all the launch codes of the nukes", etc.

Their fear is that someone not intelligent/responsible might abuse that power.

My fear is that *any* one person would have that power.

But is this really the case? If Canada insulted the president, could he just nuke one of their cities the next day? Or is this thought just a bit of fear-mongering?

Comment: I think your question is already covered here - [Does the President of the United States have the ability to deploy nuclear weapons at will?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34644/does-the-president-of-the-united-states-have-the-ability-to-deploy-nuclear-weapo)

Comment: The President can't launch nukes himself.  He can order other people to do so, but one might hope that in such a circumstance they would refuse.

Comment: @jamesqf - Indeed, but assuming that's an exaggerated example, the order to nuke a city currently occupied by IS (for example) on the pretext that they have a acquired a WMD that they intend to use on the US would be a bit less likely to be refused, but just as scary.